# do we need to check the inheritance graph of a single-inherited language for loops?

Tags: inheritance, graph, compiler-construction, semantics

I am trying to write a compiler for "[COOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_%28programming_language%29)" language. As it is written in the manual of this language, every class must at most have one parent and the parent-less classes are of children of an "Object" class.

For the semantic analysis phase of the compiler, we need to check if there is no loop in the inheritance hierarchy. for example if class a is the parent of class b and class b is the parent of class c, class c cannot be the parent of a!

But what I have come to realize is that for a single-inherited language, its not possible to have loops in the inheritance graph, if we give the fatherless classes, "object" as their parent. We just have to look if no-where in code, has anyone declared a father for "Object" !

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following two classes:

```
class A extends B {}

class B extends A {}
```

In some languages, most notably C++, the above would be illegal because you can't refer to B before its declaration and you can't inherit from a class that has only been forward-declared. So in such languages no explicit loop-check would be necessary as it is impossible to construct such a loop without running into other errors.

However in many other languages, including Java, C# and presumably COOL, it is perfectly possible to inherit from a class that is only defined later in the file (or in a different file without worrying about include-order). So in those languages the above code would be legal unless the compiler explicitly detects the loop and rejects the code because of it.